Rank of sum of two projection operators if their difference is also a projection
Suppose $E_1, E_2$ are two projection operators on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$ of characteristic $\neq 2$ such that $E_1-E_2$ is also a projection. I could deduce that $E_1 E_2=E_2 E_1= E_2$ from which it follows that $rank(E_1+E_2) \leq rank(E_1)$.
Can strict inequality arise in such a case? If yes, please give me a counter-example. Otherwise, please provide some ideas towards the proof. From the examples I can think of, I am getting equalities here. However, I cannot find a nontrivial example to get some intuition. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

If $E_1$ and $E_2$ commute, then they are simultaneously diagonalizable, which should give you a pretty good picture of everything.

@CJDowd That is something I was missing earlier. Does that mean only operators which satisfy the given conditions are of the form $E_1= Block-Diagonal(I_k, 0)$ and $E_2=Block-Diagonal(I_l,0)$ with $l \leq k$ with respect to a common basis? Then it is clear that the rank of the sum will be $k$. Am I thinking it correctly?

Yes, that is right.

@CJDowd Thank you so much for the discussion
